# Unique record per ip address on Windows DNS

Tags: domain-name-system, windows-server-2012, dhcp

I have a little problem with my DNS server under Windows domain.
My DNS server gets automatic registration from clients by dhcp.
Please consider this situation:

> - Computer PC01 with dhcp address 10.0.0.1 register itself in DNS server
> - DNS server registers PC01 with 10.0.0.1 address
> - Computer PC01 is switched off
> - After a dhcp lease time Computer PC02 is turn on
> - Computer PC02 gets dhcp address 10.0.0.1
> - DNS server registers PC02 with 10.0.0.1 address

Now I want to remotely connect to PC01, I open mstsc and I type PC01.
DNS resolution has 10.0.0.1 address and the connection starts.
But I'm connected to PC02!

How can I avoid this? Is there any way to prevent this for example allowing only one name per ip address for automatic dns registrations?

Comment: Can be something like "Name Protection" of DHCP scope properties?

Comment: Enable scavenging on the DNS server and on your DNS zone.